# Sorting object by two attributes

Tags: python, list, sorting, oop

I am trying to sort an object based mainly in one attribute but if the other attribute is the same it should also consider the second attribute. Having the idea from tuple comparision I tried the following:

However, it did not work like this. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

```
class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self, name, balance, value):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.value = value




list_not_sorted = []
print(list_not_sorted)
c1 = Customer("c1", 10, 20)
c2 = Customer("c2", 10, 40)
c3 = Customer("c3", 10, 50)
c4 = Customer("c4", 30, 0)
c5 = Customer("c5", 40, 10)
c6 = Customer("c6", 40, 20)
c7 = Customer("c7", 70, 10)

list_not_sorted.append(c1)
list_not_sorted.append(c2)
list_not_sorted.append(c3)
list_not_sorted.append(c4)
list_not_sorted.append(c5)
list_not_sorted.append(c6)
list_not_sorted.append(c7)

def key_selection(ls):
        return(ls.balance, ls.value)

list_sorted = sorted(list_not_sorted, key=lambda k: key_selection(k))

print(list_sorted[1].name)
#expected_result = [c7, c6, c5, c4, c3, c2, c1]
```

Comment: `[c7, c6, c5, c4, c3, c4, c1]` can't be the right answer; as it contains `c4` twice.

Comment: Even if you revert the order of keys in the sorting method `key_selection` then you only get `['c4', 'c5', 'c7', 'c1', 'c6', 'c2', 'c3']`. This proves the sorting works and your expected order of elements cannot be achieved only using these two keys.

Comment: Instead of `key=lambda k: key_selection(k)` you can just write `key=key_selection` (of `key=lambda k: (k.balance, k.value)`, and then you don't need `key_selection`).

Comment: It should be achieved by tuples comparison when the first value is considered as main priority and then the second avoiding this way random values in the subgroups where the first value are the same.

Comment: You have the data already sorted, and your code works fine. If you want descending order, add `reverse=True` to the `sorted` function.

Comment: @may your code is working as expected *given `sorted()` specs*. What's wrong is your expectation that it would do a descending sort instead of an ascending one.